# Как грамотно реализовать delta time?

Tags: алгоритм, время, любой-язык

Пишу проект, в котором необходимо просчитывать движение множества объектов, выполняя при этом для каждого весьма громоздкие вычисления. Дабы движение было плавным и равномерным, я использую delta time (Считаю разницу между временем до начала вычислений и после в микросекундах). И всё действительно стало лучше, за равный промежуток времени объект проходит равное расстояние, независимо от количества объектов. Но, есть одно но. Симуляции перестали быть детерменированными, то есть одинаковые начальные данные не дают одинаковый результат (в расчётах нет рандома).
Я списываю это на несовершенство просчёта времени, в этой статье в конце отдельно указан этот пункт: http://c2community.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=73634

В связи со всем этим у меня возник резонный вопрос: как мне, сохранив плавность и равномерность, иметь реалистичность и детерменированность (а она есть, если не использовать delta time)?

Ведь в более серьёзных проектах есть и то и то

Comment: Что-то я подозреваю, что никак. К примеру, многие игры, которые я видел, при нехватке времени на обработку просто замедлялись, чтобы сохранить детерминированность. Если же времени на обработку хватает, то игры просто бездействуют некоторое время, чтобы обеспечить плавность и не сделать игру слишком быстрой

Comment: считать надо через дискретные промежутки времени, а отрисовывать по дельта тайм, считать желательно чаще, иначе придется заниматься интерполяцией, если это конечно возможно

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что расчёт происходит через дискретные промежутки времени, однако, сами расчёты тратят немало времени, что в итоге и влияет на конечный результат.

Comment: Что же касается до замедления , то я об этом думал, однако тут вся загвостка в том, что тоже не поможет, так как проблема не в том, что расчёты очень долгие, объектов может быть всего пара штук, но из за несовершенного просчёта времени, в одном запуске при одинаковых расчётах проходит 300 мкс, а при другом уже 800, соответственно, результат будет уже другим.

Comment: Как насчёт сделать просчёт времени совершенным и добавить 500мкс ожидания к первому расчёту?)

Comment: Я, кажется, уловил вашу мысль, вы предлагаете в случаях слишком быстрой работы намеренно простаивать некоторое время для большей стандартизации времени? Я сейчас попробую это реализовать (однако тут сразу прослеживается такой момент: абберации со временем могут происходить и на больших отрезках времени, поэтому, думаю, будет грамотно округлять в большую сторону и дожидаться нужного времени. Расчёты прошли за 512 мкс, но программа дождётся до 1000 мкс)

Comment: Я вот тут подумал: такой способ будет несправедлив в тех случаях, когда значение в одной симуляции равно, допустим, 99, а в другой 101. В первом случае мы округлим до 100 (подождём 1 микросекунду), а в другом до 200 (будем ждать 99 микросекунд).